# How to remove \r\n when scraping a page?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have made a function by scraping a page and I run but the output gives `\r\n`. I used `strip` function to remove `\r\n` but its not working. Why and how to remove `\r\n`?
Here is the link: https://ibb.co/VtVV2fb

```
import scrapy
from .. items import FetchingItem

class SiteFetching(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Site'
    start_urls = ['https://www.rev.com/freelancers']
    transcription_page = 'https://www.rev.com/freelancers/transcription'

    def parse(self, response):
        items = {
            'Heading': response.css('#sign-up::text').extract(),
            'Earn_steps': response.css('.pb2 .lh-copy::text , .mb1::text , .mb3 .lh-copy::text').extract(), 
    }

        yield response.follow(self.transcription_page, self.trans_faqs, meta={'items':items})

    def trans_faqs(self, response):
        items = response.meta['items']
        names = {
            'name1': 'FAQ1',
            'name2': 'FAQ2', 
        }
        finder = {
            'find1': '#whatentailed p::text , #whatentailed .mr3::text',
            'find2': '#requirements p::text , #requirements .mr3::text'
        }
        for name, find in zip(names.values(), finder.values()):
            items[name] = list(map(str.strip,response.css(find).extract()))
        yield items
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What do you expect and what do you get instead?

Comment: The code seems entirely unrelated to your question.

Comment: There is ```\r\n``` showing whenever I print the result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove \r\n in command prompt after running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55983390/how-to-remove-r-n-in-command-prompt-after-running)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I have a string with tabs or newlines, I found that replacing them with '' works for me.

For example, if you have both \t and \n in your string variable, you could do this:

```
string_variable.replace('\n','').replace('\t','')
```

Works well so far.