# How to remove \r\n in command prompt after running?

Tags: python, scrapy

Whenever I run the code. it gives me `\r\n` with spaces. I used strip function but it didn't work. How to resolve this issue? Here is the link: https://ibb.co/VtVV2fb\

```
import scrapy
from .. items import FetchingItem

class SiteFetching(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Site'
    start_urls = ['https://www.rev.com/freelancers']
    transcription_page = 'https://www.rev.com/freelancers/transcription'

    def parse(self, response):
    items = {
    'Heading': response.css('#sign-up::text').extract(),
    'Earn_steps': response.css('.pb2 .lh-copy::text , .mb1::text , .mb3 .lh-copy::text').extract(), 
    }

    yield response.follow(self.transcription_page, self.trans_faqs, meta={'items':items})

    def trans_faqs(self, response):
    items = response.meta['items']
    names = {
    'name1': 'FAQ1',
    'name2': 'FAQ2', 
    }

    finder = {
    'find1': '#whatentailed p::text , #whatentailed .mr3::text',
    'find2': '#requirements p::text , #requirements .mr3::text',
    }

    for name, find in zip(names.values(), finder.values()):
        items[name] = response.css(find.strip()).extract()
    yield items
```

Comment: `strip()` can remove `\r\n` only at the end of string, but not inside. if you have  `\r\n` inside text then use `text = text.replace(\r\n', '')`

Comment: How to use it in this loop?

Comment: where do you get this `\r\n` ?  Better put example as text, not image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove \r\n when scraping a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55979642/how-to-remove-r-n-when-scraping-a-page)

Comment: Whenever a sentence completes it gives ```\r\n````. Its in the end of every sentence

Comment: I used ```items[name] = [i.strip() for i in response.css(find).extract() if i.strip()]``` but it didn't work

Comment: but where in the code you get it. Which variable has it.

Comment: you have to use `replace()` instead of `strip()` because `\r\n` is inside one long text with many sentences, not at the end of this text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strip()` can remove `\r\n` only at the end of string, but not inside. If you have `\r\n` inside text then use `text = text.replace(\r\n', '')`

it seems you get `\r\n` in list created by `extract()` so you have to use list comprehension to remove from every element on list

```
data = response.css(find).extract()
data = [x.replace('\r\n', '').strip() for x in data]
items[name] = data
```

---

**EDIT:** to remove spaces and `\r\n` between sentences you can `split('\r\n')` to create list with sentences. then you can `strip()` every sentence. And you can `' '.join()` all sentences back to one string.

```
text = 'Sentence 1\r\n    Sentence 2'

data = text.split('\r\n')
data = [x.strip() for x in data]
text = ' '.join(data)

print(text)
```

The same in one line

```
text = 'Sentence 1\r\n    Sentence 2'

text = ' '.join(x.strip() for x in text.split('\r\n'))

print(text)
```

The same with module `re`

```
import re

text = 'Sentence 1\r\n    Sentence 2'

text = re.sub('\r\n\s+', ' ', text)

print(text)
```

---

```
for name, find in zip(names.values(), finder.values()):
    data = response.css(find.strip()).extract()
    data = [re.sub('\r\n\s+', ' ', text) for text in data]
    items[name] = data
```

Comment: Thank you And How to remove spaces b/w sentences. It has so much spaces?

Comment: how about `text.replace(' ', '')` ? if it will not works then you may try module `re` which can use regex `\s+` to find longer string.

Comment: you can also `split('\r\n')` and use `strip()` on every element, and join() them back using space.

Comment: I didn't understand where to put text?

Comment: you would have to use it inside loop `for name, find ` but you have list with strings `['Sentence 1\r\n    Sentence 2']` but I use only string `'Sentence 1\r\n    Sentence 2'` .